# Django use queryset in template

Tags: django, templates

I want to check a field(=is_seller) of the table(=UserProfileInfo) and if it has some value(=0) , make some part of template disabled

and these are my codes :

models.py :

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
  user=models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile')
  companyname=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=128,verbose_name=_('companyname'))
  phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{11,11}$', message=_(u"Phone number must be 11 digit."))
  cellphone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17,verbose_name=_('cellphone'))
  tel = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True, max_length=17,verbose_name=_('tel'))
  state=models.CharField(,max_length=128,verbose_name=_('state'))
  city=models.CharField(,max_length=128,verbose_name=_('city'))
  address=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=264,verbose_name=_('address'))
  is_seller=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True, max_length=2,verbose_name=_('seller'))
  def __str__ (self):
     return self.user.username

  class Meta:
    verbose_name=_('UserProfileInfo')
    verbose_name_plural=_('UserProfileInfos')
```

view.py:

```
 def stock(request):
  st_form=StocksForm(None)
  is_seller="0"
  if request.method == "POST":
    st_form =StocksForm(data=request.POST)
    is_seller=UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).values("is_seller")
    print("<<<<<<<<<<<"+str(is_seller))
    if st_form.is_valid():
        instance=st_form.save()
        id_name=(st_form.cleaned_data.get("name"))
        instance.name=StocksName.objects.filter(id=id_name).values("name")[0]['name'] #becouse of autocomplete it was saving the value by its id and i converted to name
        instance.user=request.user
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request,"SUCCESSFUL" ,extra_tags="savestock")

    else:
        messages.error(request, "ERROR!")

else:
    st_form=StocksForm()

return render(request,'BallbearingSite/stock.html',{'stocks_form':st_form,'seller':is_seller})
```

template.html :
it doesnt work and i dont know how to correct it :

```
  {% for item in seller %}
   {% if item.is_seller=="0" %}
     <p>show some message</p>
   {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you have an error message ?

Comment: That template doesn't seem to have anything to do with that view. The view is passing `seller` as a single string. Why are you trying to iterate over it and access items within it? Your question title talks about a queryset, but you don't have a queryset.

Comment: yes, you are right . i removed the for loop and changed the code to : `{% if  is_seller == "0" %}
    <p>show some message</p>
   {% endif %}`  but also nothing happened and no message showed

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to compare a boolean (`item.is_seller`) to a string (`"0"`).

You should do:

```
{% if item.is_seller %}
```

Or:

```
{% if not item.is_seller %}
```

Comment: item.is_seller is not boolean . the form is like this : `class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (('0','buyer'),
                       ('1','seller'),
                       ('2','both'))
    is_seller = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES),label=_('title'))`